# Can't call a rest api with foreach() using parallelization

Tags: r, rest, parallel-processing, remote-access

I'm loading data from an online API. Data is paginated so I need to make consecutive calls.

Therefore I set up a parallelized foreach() loop which eventually rbind() the output.

Here's the code:

```
    library('foreach')
    library('parallel')
    library('jsonlite')

    registerDoMC(cores = parallel::detectCores())

    data <- foreach(page = 1:10, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {

        raw.data <- fromJSON(paste(endpoint, '&page=', page, sep =''))

        raw.data <- raw.data$results

        data.piece <- raw.data[c('id', 'scraper', 'title', 'text', 'ts', 'url', 'pertinence', 'source')]

        data.piece
    }
```

Endpoint is a REST url.

The loop returns NULL and furthermore it runs immediately (each call should indeed need a couple of seconds).

So it seems that the calls are skipped. If I run the same code not in parallel it works without problems.

Comment: You should include your code that sets up the parallel backend prior to the above block of code, as well as everything else required to make this example reproducible (`endpoint`, `page`, etc.).

Comment: page is already defined in the code. I added the used libraries.
Endpoint as I said is a rest url (which I cannot disclose), but any rest url could do; as I said running the code not in parallel (%do% instead of %dopar%), works perfectly, so the endpoint is not the problem.

Comment: If any URL will do then put together an example with any URL that reproduces the error.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot find a proper free json rest api example with pagination. Nevertheless I've seen many similar questions in which the actual endpoint is not provided.

Comment: Try to add `jsonlite` to the packages argument. ie: `foreach(page = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .packages = c('jsonlite')) %dopar%`

Comment: odd as it seems, the first time I tried your suggestion it seemed to work. Since it was taking too much time I opened a new instance of R and put timers to check the time gain brought by parallelization. But now it stopped working again! in both instances!

Comment: any new ideas? solving this would really speed things up.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't try to code a solution, but I recently saw a different approach to a similar question being used here: http://www.mattdancho.com/code-tools/2016/12/18/multidplyr.html

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into a similar situation and adapting my code to your situation yields the following:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

fetch.data <- function(page) {
    # confirm the url you are fetching data from ...
    url = 'http://api.paginated/?page='
    endpoint = paste0(url, page)
    print(paste0('fetching data for => ', endpoint))
    raw.data <- fromJSON(endpoint, flatten = TRUE)
    raw.data
}


no_cores <- detectCores()
cluster <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cluster)
t.start <- Sys.time()
data <- foreach(page=1:10, .combine=bind_rows, .packages=c('jsonlite')) %dopar% {
    if (page %% 4 == 0) Sys.sleep(1)
    page_data <- fetch.data(page)
    page_data <- page_data$results
    data.piece <- page_data[c('id', 'scraper', 'title', 'text', 'ts', 'url', 'pertinence', 'source')]
    data.piece
}
t.end <- Sys.time()
stopImplicitCluster()
print(t.end - t.start)
```

This code worked for me recently. The only thing you have to take care of is that you play within the api's throttling limits. This may mean you have to slow down your script - for example, for every 4th page wait for 1 sec.